# @ManyToMany of two entities with composite keys that share a field

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa

Two entities:

```
public class Employee {
  Company company;
  Long employeeId;
}
public class Project {
  Company company;
  Long projectId;
  Collection<Employee> employees;
}
```

Three tables:

- Project whose primary key is {companyId,projectId}
- Employee whose primary key is {companyId,employeeId}
- Project_Employee whose primary key is {companyId,projectId,employeeId}

Mapping in xml:

```
<entity class="domain.Project">

 <attributes>
  <many-to-many name="employees" >
   <join-table name="PROJECT_EMPLOYEE">
    <join-column name="companyId" referenced-column-name="companyId"/>
    <join-column name="employeeId" referenced-column-name="employeeId" />
    <inverse-join-column name="companyId" referenced-column-name="companyId" />
    <inverse-join-column name="projectId" referenced-column-name="projectId" />
   </join-table>
  </many-to-many>  
 </attributes>

</entity>
```

I received a error complaining companyId appearing multiple times:
Repeated column in mapping for collection: Project.employees column: companyId

Hibernate maps this with

```
<formula>companyId</formula>
```

Does JPA 1.0 support this functionality?